# error showing changed IMG tags from string (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, image, attr

I want to fetch out all img elements, from a string with Jquery, the code bellow for some reason don't output the changed Img Tag, can anyone help me on this ?

```
html='<p>lorem ipsum</p><p><img src="pic1.jpg" width="640" height="480" alt="pic1"></p><p>lorem ipsum</p><p><img src="pic2.jpg" width="25" height="25" alt="pic2"></p>';

$html = $(html);

$html.find("img").each(function() {
    $img = $(this,"img");

    if ($img.attr('width') > 25 && $img.attr('width') <= 640) {

        $a = $('<a class="example" title="'+ $img.attr('alt')+ '" alt="'+ $img.attr('alt') + '" href="'+ $img.attr('src') + '"></a>');

        $a.append($img.clone());
    }

    $img.replaceWith($a);
});

html = $html.html();

alert(html);
```

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cRx9w/

Comment: seems to be possible :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$(selector, context)` in a wrong way and `html` method only returns html content of the first matched element which in this case is the first created `p` element `<p>lorem ipsum</p>`., that's why you don't actually see what `$html` variable contains.

You can use `filter` and `wrap` methods. Note that I have created a wrapper element which is a helper for seeing html contents (that you probably expect).

```
var $html = $('<div/>').html(html);

$html.find("img").filter(function () {
    return this.getAttribute('width') > 25 && this.getAttribute('width') <= 640;
}).wrap(function () {
    return '<a class="test" title="' + this.getAttribute('alt') + '" alt="' + this.getAttribute('alt') + '" href="' + this.getAttribute('src') + '"></a>';
});

html = $html.html();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rqYAH/

Some suggestions:

- Use `console.log()`, `console.dir()`, ... for debugging purposes instead
  of `alert()`.
- Use `var` keyword for declaring variables.

Comment: @KatjaLors Because you are creating an invalid markup, http://jsfiddle.net/JyyqY/

Comment: well i want to get rid of those 2 duplicities, to just get: <p>lorem ipsum<test="sound.mp3"></p>